# How to decompose a time series with multiple seasonal components?

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, decomposition, multiple-seasonalities

I have a time series that contains double seasonal components and I would like to decompose the series into the following time series components (trend, seasonal component 1, seasonal component 2 and irregular component). As far as I know, the STL procedure for decomposing a series in R only allows one seasonal component, so I have tried decomposing the series twice. First, by setting the frequency to be the first seasonal component using the following code:

```
ser = ts(data, freq=48)
dec_1 = stl(ser, s.window="per")
```

Then, I decomposed the irregular component of the decomposed series (`dec_1`) by setting the frequency to be the second seasonal component, such that:

```
ser2 = ts(dec_1$time.series[,3], freq=336)
dec_2 = stl(ser2, s.window="per")
```

I'm not very confident with this approach. And I would like to know if there are any other ways to decompose a series that has multiple seasonalities. Also,I have noticed that the `tbats()` function in the R [forecast](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/forecast/index.html) package allows one to fit a model to a series with multiple seasonalities however, it doesn't say how to decompose a series with it.

Comment: Hi there and welcome to the site. For your two seasonal components, do they have different periodicity, e.g. is one weekly and another monthly?

Comment: Chapter 14 of Rob Hyndman, Koehler, Ord & Snyder "Forecasting with Exponential Smoothing" covers this. Hyndman also has a forecasting package in R.  I seem to recall Hyndman having posted on this site on this topic, but it might have been on his blog.

Comment: @Michelle Hi thanks for the reply. Yeah the two seasonal components have different periodicity. The first one has a periodicity of 48 (daily seasonality), while the second has a periodicity of 336 (weekly seasonality). It is a half hourly time series.

Comment: @zbicyclist I believe the forecasting package that you're on about is the 'forecast' package that I mentioned in the original post. I have had a look at the tbats function of this package but it doesnt say how to use it for decomposing. I will check out the book to see if I can find any further illustration.

Comment: Here's what I was thinking of. It was on Hyndman's blog. http://robjhyndman.com/papers/complex-seasonality/

Comment: @zbicyclist Thanks for the link to the article. The components of Figure 5 on Page 28 of the article is exactly what I'm looking for. However, it doesn't say how to implement (the decomposition) in R.

Comment: Does anyone know how to apply the tbats() function in R for decomposition?

Answer (score 12):

R's `forecast` package `bats()` and `tbats()` functions can fit BATS and TBATS models to the data. The functions return lists with a class attribute either "bats" or "tbats". One of the elements on this list is a time series of state vectors, $x(t)$, for each time, $t$.

See http://robjhyndman.com/papers/complex-seasonality/ for the formula's and Hyndman et al (2008) for a better description of ETS models. BATS and TBATS are an extension of ETS.

For example:

```
fit <- bats(myTimeseries)
fit$x
```

In this case, each row of `x` will be on fourier-like harmonic.

There are also `plot.tbats()` and `plot.bats()` functions to automatically decompose and view the components.

Answer (score 2):

R's `forecast` package now has a function `mstl()` to handle multiple seasonal time series decomposition.

This page has got more details how to use it: https://pkg.robjhyndman.com/forecast/reference/mstl.html

Answer (score 1):

The facebook [prophet](https://facebook.github.io/prophet/) package supports [multiple seasonalities](https://facebook.github.io/prophet/docs/seasonality,_holiday_effects,_and_regressors.html).

Yearly, weekly and daily seasonalities are built-in but custom seasonalities can be specified.

Here is a custom monthly seasonality:

```
df <- ...     # data to build model on or decompose
future <- ... # data to make forecasts on

m <- prophet(weekly.seasonality = FALSE)
m <- add_seasonality(m, name = 'monthly', period = 30.5, fourier.order = 5)
m <- fit.prophet(m, df)
forecast <- predict(m, future)
prophet_plot_components(m, forecast)
```

If `predict()` is called without passing in a data frame, then it will decompose the time series used to build the model.